# How can you add a custom social network to UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, pinterest, uiactivityviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems adding custom activity to UIActivityController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751891/problems-adding-custom-activity-to-uiactivitycontroller)

I have a working UIActivityViewController in my iOS 6 app that is being used to show the standard social applications (email, Facebook, Twitter, and iMessage). I am wondering if their is a way to add your own social networking sites to this controller? Specifically I am looking at Pinterest, but I am wondering how to do this in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

This is a sample code! And you can do it like they do in this sample:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/buffer-uiactivity

hope that helped

Comment: one question...could you vote up my questions I asked? It just the last three one. I would happy if you could do that, because I'm not able to ask more because ther're voted down. Thanks