# How to link to my app from the send button in the native photo viewer?

Tags: ios, photos

On my iPhone, when I view a photo I see a "send" button on the bottom toolbar; when I click this I see a menu screen with Mail, Message, Twitter, Facebook, Assign to Contact, Print, Copy and Use as Wallpaper icons.

Is there any way to get my app added to this list, and if so how do I set up my app to receive notification of this event and get access to the photo that is being viewed?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question and for whatever reason it took me a very long time to find this answer on stackoverflow that helped me. I hope it helps you.

[Problems adding custom activity to UIActivityController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751891/problems-adding-custom-activity-to-uiactivitycontroller)